# ¿Cómo eliminar un nodo de un xml sabiendo uno de sus hijos?

Tags: php, xml

Tengo un documento xml con la siguiente estructura:

```
<indicePlaneacion>    
    <planeacion>
        <claveUea>2151075</claveUea>
        <nombreUea>Introducción a la Programación para Ingenieros</nombreUea>
        <trimestre>15-P</trimestre>
        <fechaActualizacion>2016-05-30</fechaActualizacion>
        <profesor>
            <nombre>Martha </nombre>
            <apellidoPaterno>Rodriguez </apellidoPaterno>
            <apellidoMaterno>Cáliz</apellidoMaterno>
        </profesor>
        <uri>/PLAN/Datos/xml/planeacion/2151075-15-P-CD02.xml</uri>
    </planeacion>
    <planeacion>
        <claveUea>2151123</claveUea>
        <nombreUea>BASES DE DATOS</nombreUea>
        <trimestre>16-P</trimestre>
        <fechaActualizacion>2016-06-01</fechaActualizacion>
        <profesor>
            <nombre>JUAN</nombre>
            <apellidoPaterno>ZARATE</apellidoPaterno>
            <apellidoMaterno>RODRIGUEZ</apellidoMaterno>
        </profesor>
        <uri>/PLAN/Datos/xml/planeacion/2151123-16-P-CI01.xml</uri>
    </planeacion>
    .
    .
    .
</indicePlaneacion>
```

En un documento PHP puedo recibir como parámetro la uri (la uri es única en cada registro "planeación". ¿puedo desde PHP eliminar toda la planeación recibiendo como parámetro la uri?

Les agradezco su ayuda
Pdt: También puedo utilizar los elementos del profesor (nombre, apellidoPaterno y apellidoMaterno).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si, es posible lo primero que debes hacer es cargar tu archivo al DOMDocument de PHP

```
$doc = new DOMDocument; 
$doc->load('mixml.xml');
$thedocument = $doc->documentElement;
```

luego obtienes una lista de todos los nodos `planeacion`

```
$list = $thedocument->getElementsByTagName('planeacion');
```

Recorres los nodos

```
foreach ($list as $node) {

}
```

Por URI :

```
$uri = $node->getElementsByTagName('uri');
$uri->item(0)->nodeValue;
//Aqui obtienes el valor de el tag uri por ejemplo /PLAN/Datos/xml/planeacion/2151123-16-P-CI01.xml
```

Por profesor :

```
$profesor = $node->getElementsByTagName('profesor');
//Aqui podria ser nombre, apellidoPaterno, apellidoMaterno
$tag_evaluar = $profesor->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('nombre');
$valor = $tag_evaluar->item(0)->nodeValue;
//Aqui obtienes el valor, por ejemplo Martha
```

Finalmente para eliminarlo, comparas el valor que quieres eliminar

```
if($valor == 'Martha'){
    $thedocument->removeChild($node);   
}
```

Y luego imprimes lo que quedo

```
echo $doc->save('RUTA_DE_TU_XML');
```

Codigo entero :

```
<?php
    $doc = new DOMDocument; 
    $doc->load('mixml.xml');

    $thedocument = $doc->documentElement;

    //this gives you a list of the messages
    $list = $thedocument->getElementsByTagName('planeacion');
    foreach ($list as $node) {
        /*Para obtener el valor de la URI
        $uri = $node->getElementsByTagName('uri');
        $valor = $uri->item(0)->nodeValue;*/

        /*Para obtener el valor de Profesor
        $profesor = $node->getElementsByTagName('profesor');
        $tag_evaluar = $profesor->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('nombre');
        $valor = $tag_evaluar->item(0)->nodeValue;*/
        if($valor == 'Martha'){
            $thedocument->removeChild($node);
        }
    }
    echo $doc->save('mixml.xml');

?>
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50054/discussion-on-answer-by-sioesi-como-eliminar-un-nodo-de-un-xml-sabiendo-uno-de).

Comment: Del directorio como tal, no. Ya que estoy trabajando sobre windows. Sobre el archivo, intente darle todos los privilegios con chmod de PHP pero me marca un error con la ruta cuando lo intento.